# В каких случаях надо писать @override?

Tags: наследование, java, интерфейс

Здравствуйте. @override надо писать только когда мы переопределяем метод базового класса, который мы extends, или ещё и тогда, когда мы implements интерфейс?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не "надо", а "можно". Аннотация `@Override` не является обязательной для переопределённых методов. Она используется скорее для самопроверки - если в базовом классе нет метода с сигнатурой, совпадающей с методом, к которому применена аннотация `@Override`, то класс не скомпилируется. Для классов, реализующих интерфейс, такая проверка осуществляется и без аннотации - класс, реализующий интерфейс не скомпилируется, если он не реализует все методы, перечисленные в интерфейсе.

Comment: Кто-то считает можно, кто-то считает надо
>Автоматические проверки кода — в наше время обязательное умение для IDE. В IDEA их много, полезных и не очень, не буду тут все рассматривать. Но одну я ставлю обязательно, причём строго с приоритетом «Error»: это «Missing @ Override annotation».
http://habrahabr.ru/post/206714/